# Получение отдельной статистики для поддомена

Tags: веб-программирование, seo

Доброго времени суток.
Ситуация следующая.
Есть сайт вида name.ru, с него получаем статистику средствами Google Analytics.
Есть поддомен вида app.name.ru. Как получать отдельную статистику конкретно по нему?

Comment: Примените Tag Manager для нескольких суб-доменов https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#multidomain и / или просто анадитику для нескольких поддоменов https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Comment: Спасибо, @nikant25!